# Cocos2D 2.0 removed ARCH_OPTIMAL_PARTICLE_SYSTEM, How can I create pointparticles?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, ccparticlesystem

I am upgrading my Cocos2D game to Cocos2D 2.0-rc23.
I found Cocos2D 2.0 removed ARCH_OPTIMAL_PARTICLE_SYSTEM.

"
[FIX] Particle: Handles premultipled images correctly

```
Fixed possible memory leak when changing textures.
Examples: Removed ARCH_OPTIMAL_PARTICLE_SYSTEM since PointParticle is no longer supported
```

"

In my current code.

CCParticleSystem *emitter = [ARCH_OPTIMAL_PARTICLE_SYSTEM particleWithFile:@"ps.plist"];

How can I change this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trying using *CCParticleSystemQuad* instead:

```
CCParticleSystem *emitter = [CCParticleSystemQuad particleWithFile:@"ps.plist"];
```

Comment: Now the CCParticleSystemQuad has been removed from sprite builder and cocos2d-v3 as well, what's the alternative? because particle designer has embedded image texture, but cocos2d won't read them